# Reloading a DIV with another DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering whether or not it is possible to reload a certain div with its content without refreshing the page or having an external include which loads that div only. For example, when I click my button I'd like the content of my div to be refreshed, without having the whole page reloaded.

Here is an example of what I've tried to do, seems like it doesn't work well but at least explain quite fine what I'm aiming for:

```
$("#content").load("mypage.php".$("#content"));
```

Or for instance:

```
$("#content").load("mypage.php #content");
```

The file IS found and loaded, however something happens during the process. It just comes up as blank window without printing my text and the content of the div (in the original file).

Comment: You'll probably need to do an AJAX call, but it is possible.

Comment: The first one is invalid. The second one should work, assuming that `mypage.php` returns an HTML page which includes an element with ID `content`. Read more about `load`: http://api.jquery.com/load/, Loading Page Fragments.

Comment: @Felix Kling - Well in that case that's quite odd, because according to what you're saying it should work, whilst it certainly doesn't. My page does have a div with the ID "content" assigned to it, however nothing comes up. Any ideas?

Comment: Just refer to the Loading Page Fragments http://api.jquery.com/load/ and it will give you what you want. The load also has a callback on complete so you know when it is finished.

Comment: You can use Ajax, but you can also use element.replaceChild() method

Comment: He doesn't need AJAX if he is just loading static content from another page, `.load()` will do that. `mypage.php` is on the same server/domain right?

Comment: is "mypage.php" the current page?  What data is in the div that needs refreshing?

Comment: To all who mention Ajax: That's exactly what `.load` is doing! It makes an Ajax call, retrieves the HTML and then sets it as new content of the selected element(s).

Comment: @Givi: You cannot say either or. You use Ajax to get the data and then DOM manipulation methods to insert the data.

Comment: "mypage.php" is the very same page, I'm simply trying to refresh its content. It just loads a blank white window when I try to use the method, even though I believe I'm doing everything according to the rules. The div I'm trying to refresh contains some HTML call and PHP functions within it as well.

Comment: @Tommy: I fear there is not really much we can say without more information. I recommend to create a simple example and try to get it working. When/how/where are you calling `$("#content").load("mypage.php #content");`?

Comment: @Felix: I call this function upon a successful submission of my form. There is no problem with the rest of my code though, the problem is with this function only.

Comment: @FelixKling why not ? you can create documentFragment and then toggle elements with replaceChild

Comment: @Tommy: How are you submitting the form? If you want to update the div without reloading the page, you have to submit the form via Ajax as well. Otherwise you will just be redirected after the form was submitted.

Comment: @Givi: And how do you get the updated data? Of course you can create DOM elements with JavaScript and populate it with data generated with JS, but here in this case the OP needs the data from the server! You don't have to choose between Ajax OR DOM manipulation. These are two different things.

Comment: @FelixKling Well in that case, you're right.

Comment: It's possible that the form is getting cached.  Try adding a timestamp as a query string
$("#content").load("mypage.php?t=23433 #content");

Comment: @Givi: I disable the submission, I meant to say that I call this function on a successful validation of my form. It doesn't do anything at this point, it used to alert me that the validation is fine but I disabled it in order to test this reloading thing. In other words, the form doesn't get submitted in the end of my process.

Comment: Another possibility is that it's not finding the page.

try to set the path a little more relative

$("#content").load("../mypage.php #content");

Comment: @Javaslu: Not much of a change, still a blank white page. Although I find it hard to believe it can't find the page, considering the fact it's the very same page I'm trying to load. I might be missing something, though.

Comment: @Tommy: Without seeing the code or at least simplified version, we can only guess.

Comment: Well problem is that I've got quite much of a code in both of my pages, I'll try to come up with a live example though.

Comment: I've edited my main question with an example of a file I'm trying to include.

Comment: Sorry for the bump but is anyone having any ideas?

Comment: @TommyNaidich You can start a bounty if you want to bump.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to update an element with the newest content.

Let's say you open a web page now, edit a certain element, then open the edited one in a new tab, and you want an element from the first tab to get the latest content of a new tab.

I made this really simple function, **no jQuery needed**. Check it out:

```
function reloadElement(selector, url){
    if(!url) url = location.href;
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var r = this.responseText;
            container.innerHTML = r;
            var e = container.querySelector(selector).outerHTML;
            var l = document.querySelector(selector);
                l.outerHTML = e;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Here's how it works:

- The function expects two parameters: a CSS selector and an optional url where to reload from.
  If the url parameter is not passed, current page's url is used instead.
- It loads the page in an artificial container and finds a required element by a path, fetches its content and updates the real one.